# How do a open a Speak Dialog (or Dashboard Application) from within code?

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor, speak

So I need the ability to trigger a Speak Application (either a Dialog or a Dashboard) from within code.  This is going to happen from a custom command I have created that will process specific logic about the current context to determine which speak dialog to display.  Is there a way to do this from within c# code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open a SPEAK dialog using the `SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog` command.

Example:

```
SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(new ModalDialogOptions(url)
{
  Width = "100",
  Height = "200",
  Response = true,
  ForceDialogSize = true
});
```

The `url` parameter is the Sitecore path of the SPEAK page, e.g: `/sitecore/client/applications/dialogs/myPage`

This should work if calling the dialog from a back end code.

Reference:

- https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/development/open_a_speak_dialog

Comment: Seems weird to trigger a Speak application using a Sheer method.  :-)